# How to control object's lifecycle with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, lifecycle

I have Guice-injected objects which have two lifecycle methods `bind()` and `unbind()`. The method `bind()` is called automatically after the object is instantiated by Guice using following annotated method:

```
@Inject
final void autoBind() {
    bind();
}
```

What I want to do is to call the method `unbind()` on the old (current) object before a new instance of the object is created by Guice. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would not advise that you just annotate arbitrary methods with @Inject. Keep it to constructors, and occasionally for optional injection and/or field injection.

What you are trying to do does sound a bit weird, and I'm not sure it's exactly what you want. Can you please provide more background on what you're trying to do because maybe a different approach is better. There are definitely some concerns here with thread safety and how you manage references.

Based on what you described, an approach like what @meverett mentioned would probably work. If the objects you have are `Foo`s, it would look something like this.

```
// Later on be sure to bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class);
final class FooProvider implements Provider<Foo> {
  private final Provider<Foo> unboundFooProvider;

  private Foo currentInstance;

  @Inject FooProvider(@Unbound Provider<Foo> unboundFooProvider) {
    this.unboundFooProvider = unboundFooProvider;
  }

  @Override public Foo get() {
    if (currentInstance != null) {
      currentInstance.unbind();
    }
    currentInstance = unboundFooProvider.get();
    currentInstance.bind();
    return currentInstance;
  }
}
```

NOTE that your `@Unbound Foo` provider would generate `Foo`s without invoking any special methods. The regular `FooProvider` keeps track of state and deciding when to `bind()` and `unbind()` the instances. Please be careful with how you manage multiple instances and use them with multiple threads.

Also, just to be clear: I'm using `@Unbound` since the methods you want to invoke are called `bind()` and `unbind()`. I'm not using "bound" in the Guice sense.

Also note... off the top of my head I'm pretty sure Providers are treated as singletons, so maintaining state like this will work. If it didn't, you could obviously just create a level of indirection with some kind of singleton factory (but that shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried this solution and I think it's what I need but the problem is in the `Provider<Foo>` injected in the constructor, which causes an endless loop. That's because Guice looks for the `Provider` of `Foo`, finds the `FooProvider`, and then recursively tries to inject the `Provider<Foo>` in its constructor. If you know how to overcome this issue, please let me know! Otherwise it would do what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @eQui - Did you use a binding annotation for the internal Provider<Foo> that you inject? As far as Guice is concerned, `Foo` and `@Unbound Foo` are two completely different types. Take a look at the `com.google.inject.Key` class. That's the type Guice uses internally for distinguishing types. Notice it is type information (like class) + binding annotation info (like @Unbound). You should have no circular dependency as long as `@Unbound Foo` doesn't directly or indirectly depend on `Foo`.

Comment: If you still have trouble with this, ask me more questions in the comments and/or post your code (by adding an update to the question)

Comment: Okay, so I created a binding annotation `@Unbound` and annotated the `Provider<Foo>` as you did, so my `FooProvider` looks exactly the same as yours. Now I have another question - how do I bind the internal `Provider<Foo>` to the `@Unbound` annotation? Thanks!

Comment: @eQui: Whenever `Foo` is bound (in the Guice sense), `Provider<Foo.` is also bound. i.e. - if you can inject `Foo`, you can inject `Provider<Foo>`. Similarly, if `@Unbound Foo` is injectable, then `@Unbound Provider<Foo>` is also injectable. So you can do either `@Provides @Unbound Foo` provider method or `bind(Foo.class).annotatedWith(Unbound.class).to*`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Previous responses address other concerns nicely, so to just answer the question:

Netflix introduced [governator in github](https://github.com/Netflix/governator) in 2012 to "[enhance Google Guice to provide](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki) ... [lifecycle management](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki/Lifecycle-Management)".  It provides annotations (`@PreConfiguration`, `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy`, and others), classpath scanning & auto binding, and other features.  [Bootstrapping](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki/Bootstrapping) is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could have a provider that keeps a reference to the current object. When you call get on the provider it would unbind the last object, construct the new one and save the reference to it.

though I'm not really sure why you would want to do something like this since other objects can in theory still be referencing it